# Access comboxbox selection needs to change value in label control

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

On a form, I have a combobox, with the RowSource coming from a query (specifically, a calculated field in the query). When the user makes a selection, I want to update a label on the same form with a different column from that same query, but of course associated to the selection.

I'm fine with VBA and writing queries and whatnot, but I am not very familiar with Access forms.

By the way, I tried searching for an answer to this, but it was quite difficult because I don't know what this thing is really called that I am trying to do. A good link to a site explaining this would be perfectly fine (no need to write a bunch of stuff here if it already exists elsewhere).

Comment: Yeah, I had forgotten about it. Thanks for the polite reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the After Update event of my combo box, `cboUserID`, I can set a label control, `lblFoo`, to the value of the second column in the selected row of the combo.

```
Me.lblFoo.Caption = Me.cboUserID.Column(1)
```

If your combo box is bound to a field in the form's record source, you may want to do that same operation from the form's On Current event also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column property to refer to anything other than the bound column of a combo.

```
Rowsource: SELECT ID, SName, FName FROM Table

Me.MyCombo.Column(2)
```

This would return FName.

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224084(v=office.11).aspx

```
Me.MyLabel.Caption = Me.MyCombo.Column(2)
```

Comment: I'm trying to update the text in a label, which should be based on the value selected in the combobox. The combobox seems to be working fine. I think I need to do something to the label to make it know where to get its value from. Either that, or I am missing the point of your answer.

Comment: Use the after update event of the combobox. Put some code to set the caption value of your label to the relevant column of the combo (see above).